# UILabel won't show in multiple line

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is my `UILabel`:

```
let lblTitle: UILabel = {
    let lbl=UILabel()
    lbl.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
    lbl.textAlignment = .center
    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
    lbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    lbl.numberOfLines=0
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return lbl
}()
```

I have added `lineBreakMode` and set `numberOfLines=0` which supposed to enable the multiline. My view is added programatically:

```
scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true

scrollView.addSubview(lblTitle)
lblTitle.text="Testing testing testing testing"
lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive=true
lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true

scrollView.addSubview(btnGetChoose)
btnGetChoose.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
btnGetChoose.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive=true
btnGetChoose.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
btnGetChoose.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lblTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
```

Why my `UILabel` won't show in multiple line?

Comment: It looks like your label's width or leading/trailing anchor need to be set to something. Without it, your label will just grow infinitely wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by setting label's leading/trailing anchor as suggested by @keithbhunter

```
lblTitle.text="Testing testing testing testing"
lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive=true
lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
lblTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive=true
lblTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive=true
```

Comment: no need to set centerX if you already set leading & trailing / left&right

Comment: Tested and found that `centerXAnchor` is necessary for the UILabel to show in multiple line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `equal  to` with `greater than or equal to`.

Try this

```
lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50).isActive=true
```

Also note, you should use leading and trailing anchors (or width constraint) to provide content size to its super view (scrollview).

Comment: I have solved this problem by setting label's leading/trailing anchor as suggested by @keithbhunter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width or leading & trailing to wrap

```
lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width / 2).isActive=true
```